# Restrict the overlay boundaries of dialog to be within only one layoutUnit that contains it

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I am using primefaces `dialog` (with `modal=true`).  I need to restrict the overlay of dialog box to be within one `layoutUnit` which contains it & do not spread the overlay on the entire page(which contains several `layoutUnit`s).

Answer (score 0):

You will likely have to create your own modal overlay display it when you show the dialog.

```
<div class="customoverlay" />
```

You will need to create a stylesheet class for a div file that spreads it across the parent container, sets its `zindex` to a number higher than anything else in that layout unit except for the dialog, and you will probably want to set its `opacity` to a value of your choosing.

In the javascript that displays your dialog you will also need to make a jQuery call to display your overlay as well.

```
exampleDialog.show();
jQuery('.customoverlay').css('display', 'inline');
```

The javascript that hides your dialog you will want to do the same thing as above except set the `display` style to `none`.